# On Windows 2008 R2 Java Applet throws "Publisher cannot be vertified" error

Tags: applet, 64-bit

I have a signed Java Applet which works just fine other than Windows 2008 R2 64-bit machine. On Windows 2008 R2 64-bit machine I am getting "Publisher cannot be vertified" error.

I have another applet which is just working fine in the same environment.

Error dialog contains details:

Warning security

The publisher cannot be verified by a trusted source. Code will be treated as unsigned.

Name: $FileApplet

Java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: OCSP response error: MALIFORMED_REQUEST

Thanks in advance,
Rahul

Comment: More details are needed to solve this problem. What browser do you use? What are the exact commands that you used to sign each applet? Have you tryed to sign the working applet the same way, that you signed not working one?